# Serve public files in django

Tags: reactjs, django

I am using Django with React. And I want to serve react public files from Django.

but django static files are served with a prefix url, like this

```
/static/favicon.ico
/static/manifest.json
```

but I want to serve files like this, without any prefix.

```
/favicon.ico
/manifest.json
/serviceworker.js
```

So how do I do it? please help

Comment: Is that a good idea? What happens if a user uploads a file (to your `media` folder) with the same name of an existing URL path? You can make exceptions for files like `favicon.ico` and `manifest.json` in your web server (nginx etc) configuration.

Comment: But what about development?

Comment: Are you fussed about a missing favicon during development? If yes, you should use a proper web server during development too.

Comment: @Selcuk , manifest.json!

Comment: I want to test pwa, where we need manifest.json and serviceworker.js in the root path.

Comment: You can always define URL redirects in your `urls.py` for those special cases, e.g. `re_path(r'^manifest\.json$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/manifest.json', permanent=True))`.

Comment: I tried it but browser shows warning and does not allow it for PWA. But fortunately I have found a very good way to do this and answered it bellow. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched a lot about this and eventually found this as the best and efficient way

**app/urls.py**

```
import os
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from public import views

urlpatterns = []

SERVE_DIR = os.path.join(str(settings.BASE_DIR), "folder_path")
if os.path.exists(SERVE_DIR):
    files = os.listdir(SERVE_DIR)
    for f in files:
        urlpatterns += [path(f, views.public)]
```

**app/views.py**

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve

def public(request, public_url):
    public_folder = os.path.join(str(settings.BASE_DIR), "folder_path")
    return serve(request, public_url, document_root=public_folder)
```

Comment: Good job! Solved my problem as well

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Static Files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/)

Changing **STATIC_URL** from '/static/' to '/' should work.

Comment: No, it does not work and shows error. It has security issue.

Comment: Use a webserver to serve static files. Catch static files by using the extensions i.e .json

Comment: that includes a lot of work and also not easeful during development.